# Prevent conversion to exponent format in Java for Android while using BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am trying to divide **5** by **0.0005** using BigDecimal in Java in Android.

The result what I get is **1E+4** while i want to show **10000** as the result.

Right now what I am doing is :

```
BigDecimal aaaa = new BigDecimal("5");
BigDecimal bbbb = new BigDecimal("0.0005");

aaaa.divide( bbbb , new MathContext( 16, RoundingMode.DOWN) );
```

I want **16** digit precision with **RoundingMode.DOWN**

**Scenerio 1** : Does not work as expected

```
aaaa = 5
bbbb = 0.0005
result => 1E+4
required => 10000
```

**Scenerio 2** : Work as expected

```
aaaa = 100
bbbb = 3
result => 33.33333333333333
required => 33.33333333333333
```

Why there are different output **format** for both answers with exact same code. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: 1E+4 and 1000 are the same value. They only differ in how they are printed. If you want to influence how it's printed use the appropriate methods in `DecimalFormat`. There's nothing wrong with the dividing method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple. I got exactly what I want by using

```
BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
```

This show output as I require without using `DecimalFormat`

```
5 / 0.0005 => 10000 (and not in exponential format as => 1E+4)
100 / 3    => 33.33333333333333
```

Answer (score 3):

[`BigDecimal.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString())

> Returns the string representation of this BigDecimal, using scientific
>   notation if an exponent is needed.

You can use [`BigDecimal.toPlainString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString())

> Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent
>   field.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal aaaa = new BigDecimal("5");
    BigDecimal bbbb = new BigDecimal("0.0005");

    BigDecimal result = aaaa.divide( bbbb , new MathContext( 16, RoundingMode.DOWN) );
    System.out.print(result.toPlainString()); //10000
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but then when having other exponential notation say `1.012345678912345+E20` will give me `101234567891234500000`. But then i just require 16 digit precision.

Comment: @kanudo: Then you will have to use formatting with `DecimalFormat`. `toString()` and `toPlainString()` are quite simple and only return these formats.